# How do I fix my React contact form using EmailJS for backendless forms?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, contact-form

I am trying to add a working email contact form in my development portfolio using [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/), as there is no back-end. I've included e.preventDefault statements in my code as instructed, however when the form is submitted the page seems to refresh and send the user back to the main page of the website. I've done multiple tests and I never receive any emails. I receive no errors in the console. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a link to my codebase on github: https://github.com/charliec1665/charliec-dev-portfolio

To the specific contact component: https://github.com/charliec1665/charliec-dev-portfolio/blob/main/src/components/Contact/index.js

Here is the code for the hooks used to handle submission:

```
    // handle form submission and loading state
    const [formSent, setFormSent] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const form = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const req = {
            from_name: name,
            from_email: email,
            message: message
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        sendEmail(req);
    }

    const sendEmail = req => {
        const params = req;
        window.emailjs.send('portfolio_contact', 'template_suo050u', params, 'BfYQUzIt-ih1oyqmY')
            .then(res => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setFormSent(true);
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(e => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }
```

And this is the JSX for the column that includes the form:

```
                    <Col>
                        {isLoading ?
                            <Spinner animation='border' variant='info'/>
                            : formSent ? (
                                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                    <p className='success-text'> Your message has been sent! </p>
                                </div>
                            )
                            : <></>
                        }
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Group id='contact-form' ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='my-3'>
                                {/* name input */}
                                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                    <Form.Control type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name' autoComplete='name' defaultValue={name} onBlur={handleChange} style={{ width: '65%' }} />
                                </div>
                                {/* email input */}
                                <div className='my-3 d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                    <Form.Control type='email' placeholder='Email' name='email' autoComplete='email' defaultValue={email} onBlur={handleChange} style={{ width: '65%' }} />
                                </div>
                                {/* message text area */}
                                <div className='my-3 d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                    <Form.Control as='textarea' placeholder='Tell me about your project' name='message' rows={5} defaultValue={message} onBlur={handleChange} style={{ width: '65%' }} />
                                </div>
                                {/* if errorMessage print errorMessage text to alert user */}
                                {errorMessage && (
                                    <div className='my-3 d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                        <p className='error-text'>{errorMessage}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                <div className='my-3 d-flex justify-content-center'>
                                    <Button type='submit' className='btn'>Send</Button>
                                </div>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
```

Comment: Are you using a component for your forms? This is just a guess, but looks like you've added the `onSubmit` to the `Form.Group` but likely it should be on the `Form` since that's what you would do in HTML

Comment: @aug Brilliant! That was the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a formal answer -- most React `<Form>` components follow the conventions of the HTML5 spec for the original `<form>` element. Typically yhe `onSubmit` would live on the `<Form>`. It looks like you're adding it to the `<Form.Group>` which would not work.